# A factoring algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, factoring, gcd-and-lcm, computational-mathematics

I haven't proved it (yet) but it seems like 
$\gcd(a-b,m+n)|am+bn$. Could this be used to design a factoring agorithm?

A big number $N$ could be analyzed finding $a,b,m,n\in\mathbb Z_+$ such that $N=am+bn$, with recursion due to one of the terms, to find $a,b,m,n$ such that $\gcd(a-b,m+n)>1$.

---

The strategy of choose $a,b,m,n$ has two goals, to choose $am$ close to $N$ and to increase the probability to get $\gcd >1$. The goals may be difficult or even impossible to combine, but one should remember the words of Carl Pomerance: "It isn't proved that factoring has to be hard."

Comment: $am + bn = (a-b)m + b(m+n)$ hence the divisibility. I think your algorithm is likely slower than the naive one, which only requires checking numbers up to $\sqrt{N}$ to find all factors. Given $N$ and $am$, you will need to factor $N - am$ to get $bn$, so you are looking at doing a bunch of factoring of numbers of size roughly $N/2$. As $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a concave function, I would expect the divide and conquer technique would be less efficient. (But this is just a kneejerk guess.)

Comment: this will only work if $\gcd(a-b,m+n)$ is greater than 1. I assume this will not happen most of the time

Comment: @WillieWong I dont think thi is a valid argument. he can skip numbers N-am that are hard to factor,  m can be chosen that N-am is smaller than a, so N-am can be a small number that is easy to factor

Comment: what happened when you tried it out?

Comment: @WillieWong -Thanks for your aspects!

Comment: @miracle173 - I have tryed some simple cases, but haven't really designed an algorithm yet.